# Create boxplot from Pandas DataFrame with multiindex columns

Tags: pandas, boxplot, multi-index

I have DataFrame with multi-index columns (alphas, receiver, run).

I have 10 runs, multiple alphas, and 2 receivers.

I want to create boxplot that would include two boxes (one for each receiver - rec1, rec2) for every alpha value over the 10 runs.

Something like this: 
[image: desired boxplot figure]

```py
repetitions = vectors_toPlot.repetition.unique()
alphas = [0.02, 0.03] # this is example, final version will have more values
receivers = ["rec1", "rec2"]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['alphas', 'receiver', 'run'])

multiDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=index)
# fill it with values

print(multiDf.head())

alphas          0.02                                                  \
receiver        rec1                                                   
run              0.0         1.0         2.0         3.0         4.0   
0         11744000.0  11744000.0  11744000.0  11744000.0  11744000.0   
1         11744000.0  11744000.0  11744000.0  11744000.0  11744000.0   
2         12331200.0  12331200.0  12331200.0  12331200.0  12331200.0   
3         12624800.0  12624800.0  12624800.0  12624800.0  12624800.0   
4         12331200.0  12331200.0  12331200.0  12331200.0  12331200.0
```

I tried various combination of `df.boxplot()` playing with `by` and `columns` but I can't make sense of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want [sns' boxplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html):

```
# set up the index
alphas = [0.02, 0.03] # this is example, final version will have more values
receivers = ["rec1", "rec2"]
runs = np.arange(4)
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([alphas, receivers, runs], names=['alphas', 'receiver', 'run'])

# toy data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,1, (10,len(index))), columns=index)

# plot
sns.boxplot(x='alphas', y=0, hue='receiver', data=df.unstack().reset_index())
```

Output

[image]